# Hash database values such that NULL is assigned an integer, not NULL

Tags: sql, database, hash, null

I'm interested in hashing database field values as part of an attempt to detect changes in tables.

The database in question (Vertica) has a HASH function, mainly for internal use I guess, as well as other hashes.  The internal function assigns a non-null hash value to NULL (in fact, it differs for NULLs of different datatypes).

I might end up using that internal hash function, but if it turns out that its statistical properties and collision avoidance aren't that good, how can I use other provided functions like md5 etc (I don't need strong cryptographic hashes) when they all send NULL to NULL?

Of course I could just assign another hash value to NULL, but I don't know an elegant way to do that.  (As opposed to expanding the set of hash values and adding one for NULL.)

Comment: a null value means there's no data to hash.  You'll have to manually assign what should happen on a null value.  Without seeing some code it is difficult for us to provide a contextually relevant solution.

Comment: Well, what got me thinking about this is that the internal HASH function for Vertica clearly does assign a value to NULL.  I assume that must involve acting on the binary representation.

Comment: The context: I want to detect changes in tables.  One table in particular has billions of rows and approx. 40 cols of different datatypes.  Instead of asking "did the table change at all", I want to break it down into date ranges.  (So the hashes would be over all the rows in each date range.)  I can't use triggers.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply select the part of the tables (I mean select the required columns from the table), generate a Hash Function of that queried data, and compare it the next time.

**The query to a table is another table. Track change to that new table.**